# Getting "IndexError: list index out of range" on my python script

Tags: python, bash

I have the below program that I found and trying to edit and make it work.  I am using Kbuntu  with Python 2.7.  I get below error when I run the scripts:

> rm: cannot remove ‘Devices_Config_Pull.xls’: No such file or directory
>   rm: cannot remove ‘Devices_Config_Pull.zip’: No such file or directory
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "config_pull.py", line 17,
>   in 
>       connection = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range

```
import os,sys,string
sys.path.append('/home/user/python/lib/lib/python')
import pexpect
import xlwt
import credential

os.system('rm Devices_Config_Pull.xls') #This will remove previews created spreadsheet
os.system('rm Devices_Config_Pull.zip') #This will remove previews created zip

list_devices=open('list.txt').readlines() #This will read the list of devices that file is on the same location as the script


email, UID, passwd, enable = credential.cred() #This is a module that I created that will store all of credential
*connection = sys.argv[1]
connection = int(connection)*

 ### If the argument is 1 it will telnet into the devices if the argument is 2 it will ssh into the devices
if connection == 1:
        tunnel = 'telnet '
        conmess = 'telnet'
elif connection == 2:
        tunnel = ('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ' + UID + ' ')
        conmess = 'SSH'
######## This for loop block. is the loop for telnet/ssh into the devices

wbk = xlwt.Workbook() #Create an excel workbook
font = xlwt.Font() 
font.bold = True
#style = .XFStyle()
style.font = font     < lines omitted>
```

Comment: How are you executing the script? I.e., what command are you running on the command line?

Comment: `connection = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range` means that you called the program without any parameters. Its common to catch that sort of thing and print a usage statement.

Comment: You could strip out 90% of the script and still have an example that fails. The system calls, opening files, getting credentials, excel, have nothing to do with the problem. As stands, you leave the appearance that you didn't really try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sys.argv needs input from command line 
you can't remove file before it exists.

```
import os,sys,string
import pexpect
import xlwt
import credential
sys.path.append('/home/user/python/lib/lib/python')

if os.path.isfile('Devices_Config_Pull.xls'):
    os.system('rm Devices_Config_Pull.xls') #This will remove previews created spreadsheet
if os.path.isfile('Devices_Config_Pull.zip'):   
    os.system('rm Devices_Config_Pull.zip') #This will remove previews created zip

list_devices=open('list.txt').readlines() #This will read the list of devices that file is on the same location as the script


email, UID, passwd, enable = credential.cred() #This is a module that I created that will store all of credential
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('need cmd line parameters')
    exit()
*connection = sys.argv[1]
connection = int(connection)*

 ### If the argument is 1 it will telnet into the devices if the argument is 2 it will ssh into the devices
if connection == 1:
        tunnel = 'telnet '
        conmess = 'telnet'
elif connection == 2:
        tunnel = ('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ' + UID + ' ')
        conmess = 'SSH'
######## This for loop block. is the loop for telnet/ssh into the devices

wbk = xlwt.Workbook() #Create an excel workbook
font = xlwt.Font() 
font.bold = True
#style = .XFStyle()
style.font = font     < lines omitted>
```

Comment: Thanks .. I was not passing any argument  :)